# NetSuite RestLet call from SuiteLet Client

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to call a RestLet webservice/URL from another SuiteScript. As i understand I need to use the http/https module to do so. But I am not able to find some example or steps to do so.

Planning to use this code in SS2.0-

```
var response = http.post({
url: 'https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=601&deploy=1',
body: myDataObj, // json object
headers: headerObj // json obj
});
```

The below code works for me.

```
            var nameValue = "arin";
            var myDataObj = {
                "name" : nameValue
            };
            var myRequest = {};
            myRequest.headers = {};
            myRequest.headers["Authorization"] = 'NLAuth nlauth_account=TSTDRV158xxxx,nlauth_email=XXXX,nlauth_signature=XXXX,nlauth_role=3';
            myRequest.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json';
            myRequest.headers["Accept"] = '*/*';
            myRequest.url = 'https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=601&deploy=1'; // RESTlet
                                                                                                                // URL
            myRequest.method = "POST";
            myRequest.body = JSON.stringify(myDataObj);
            // myRequest.body = myDataObj;
            var myResponse = https.post(myRequest);
```

And reading the response data for JSON return ...

```
        log.debug("Resonse", myResponse.body);
        log.debug("Resonse", myResponse.code);          
        var data = myResponse.body;             
        var retObj = JSON.parse(data);              
        log.debug("Resonse Ret city - ", retObj.city);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic example of how to do it:

```
var myRequest = {};
myRequest.headers = {};
myRequest.headers["Authorization"] = 'NLAuth nlauth_account=TSTDRVXXXXX, nlauth_email=xxx@xxx.com, nlauth_signature=XXXXXXX, nlauth_role=3';
myRequest.headers["contentType"] = 'application/json';
myRequest.url = 'https://XXXXXXXXX'; //RESTlet URL
myRequest.body = myDataObj;
var myResponse = https.post(myRequest);
```

Be careful exposing this on clientside scripts. You don't want to expose your credentials.

Comment: There is a problem I found while returning the data... If the Server return the data as "JSON.stringify(retObj)" then I need to parse 2 times at the client side to get the data....
```
var data =JSON.parse(myResponse.body);        
var retObj = JSON.parse(data); 
log.debug("Resonse Ret data - ", data.city); 
log.debug("Resonse Ret ret - ", retObj.city);
```
First city give no value... 2nd one gives...

Comment: What's the problem? You are getting the data you need already.

Comment: Yes... I am getting the Data. 
The problem what I see is that when consuming the service from who is sending the data using stringify instead of the obj prop {}.
_Just wondering if I can find a way for that scenario also_